# Dual-Boot Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

How can I Dual-Boot Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu(I already have Ubuntu 12.04 installed), When every time I try to create a partition it comes up with an error "One more partitions are busy on /dev/sda"

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have installed windows 7 and want to create partition.. use the gparted... and after that install windows 7. boot ubuntu cd again and check how to recover the grub 2. if dont see windows 7 in boot list run ubuntu and in the terminal update-grub and you are the man.